# Excerpt The Post In Wordpress Post

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have the following code, however it appears the read more link is not working, please would someone mind assisting, ive activated the excerpt in functions file:

Query post below:-

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php the_excerpt('Read more...'); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More...</a>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this editor button:

[image]

to split the content:

[image]

or

[image]

Then it will show up like this on your overview page:

[image]

In the default theme Twenty Twelve you use this code:

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
```

to display the `Continue reading` link.

So in your case you could use:

```
<?php the_content("Read more ...");?>
```

Comment: hi there, i did this and its not working, hence i thought it was something to do with my php code

Comment: can you explain more what you mean by `the read more link is not working`? Do you mean the link after the `the_excerpt` function in your code. Ps: you should use `posts_per_page` instead of the old `showposts` parameter.

Comment: as in there is no read more link. I will have a look and advise shortly

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that has always served my projects well has been to declare a simple function in `functions.php` as follows:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '… <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More ...' . '</a>';
}
```

And then call the excerpt where needed using:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Hope this helps, the WP codex also has some awesome documentation on the excerpt http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt